# W: Lint/Void: Literal <<-DOC used in void context

Tags: ruby

The code goes:

```rb
def stratified_subsampling(arr, n_strata, n_points, srand)
  <<-DOC
  The function samples "n_points" points from an array "arr".
  It preserves the original distribution of the data. "n_strata"
  is the number of strata to devide the values in. Have to find a
  trade-off for this value, but I think that as a rule of thumb,
  10 bins should be fair enough in most cases.
  DOC

  vs = arr.sort
...
```

Rubocop says:

```
W: Lint/Void: Literal <<-DOC used in void context.
  <<-DOC
  ^^^^^^
```

I don't understand what that means and how should I fix it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have a string literal here that you do absolutely nothing with. Does it need to be a string literal? A comment should serve just fine.

Comment: 1. Thank you! 2- It's a comment. How do I supress Rubocop warning? Would you mind adding that to the answer?

Comment: It's not a comment, it's a string literal. You can suppress cops by using magic comments `# rubocop:disable Lint/Void`

Comment: I see. it's supposed to be a multi-line comment. Then I should just use `#` on every line of the comment?